# Shortcode not working on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm making a plugin and I don't understand why my shortcode doesn't work if I insert into a woocommerce product page.

It does work if I add it elsewhere on another page, just not on product pages.

The shortcode is added very simply:

```
add_shortcode('testing',  'testingform');

    function testingform() {
       ob_start();
    echo 'Width:<br>
  <input type="text" name="width" id="width"><br>
Height:<br>
  <input type="text" name="height" id="height"><br>
Scale:<br>
  <input type="text" name="scale" id="scale"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn"><br>
<button type="button" id="stripbtn">Show Strips</button>

<div class="wallpapercontainer">
<div class="holder">
  <div class="wallpaper">

  </div>
</div>
  <div class="heightbar"></div>
  <div class="widthbar"></div>
</div>';
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hi jojo, can I see your shortcode's function? there could be some codes there that is making your shortcode to not work. Also is your function inside a class?

Comment: Not in a class. Has been added. Sorry for slow reply.

Comment: Where and how in a product page?

Comment: It's being put in through a shortcode in a text/code module in divi, the same way I'm doing it on other pages.

Comment: So mostly nobody can really help you because we can't reproduce your issue that is very specific where a commercial theme and a module are involved (and maybe other customizations)…

Comment: hmm not sure if this works.. could you please change this code

`$output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;`

to `return ob_get_clean();` lets see if this works.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yeah I understand that. Will probably look to devs of the theme to find out. Phil, didn't work :(